# input value null wating for method response

Tags: angular

I have 3 components that look like this

```
<grandparent-component>
 <parent-component>
  <child-component>
   </child-component>
  </parent-component>
</grandparent-component>
```

in grandparent-component I have a server-method with a response.
I need to use that response in child-component.
I have tried to do that using 2 Inputs, but the value is empty before executing the method.
Basically, I have the currentUser in parent component but in child-component is {}.

How can I handle this?

child-component

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() currentUser;

 ngOnInit() {
  this.initializeForm(this.currentUser);
}

initializeForm(user) {
... }
```

parent-component

```
<app-child-component [currentUser]="currentUser"></app-child-component>
```

ts code

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() currentUser;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

grandparent-component

```
 <div class="col-sm-8">
    <app-parent-component [currentUser]="currentUser"></app-parent-component>
</div>
```

ts code

```
 export class GrandParentComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeCurrentUser();
  }

  initializeCurrentUser(id) {
    this.service.getById(id).subscribe(response => {
      this.currentUser = response;
    });
  }
```

Comment: I'm not shure what you're trying but you can think of a better solution using a service like here maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60152909/9043915

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to only show the descendants if there is a value?

Like this:

**grandparent-component**

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <app-parent-component *ngIf="currentUser" [currentUser]="currentUser">
    </app-parent-component>
</div>
```

Or do you want to do something more complex?

Comment: it's something more complex, but i've minimised everything for my question

Comment: So handling changes, like Andrei's answer? Or still something different?

Comment: Can you do a basic repro in stackblitz demonstrating what the problem is?

Comment: Cheers. Still not sure what the problem is though?

Comment: the problem is that the currentUser doesn't get to the child component

Comment: Once I've fixed the GrandparentComponent delcaration in app.module, it works for me. I've forked your example and have displayed the current user properties. I also added an *ngIf guard in the child component for when currentUser isn't available. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qimpwd But in essence, I didn't see a problem with your example.

Comment: I understand, sorry but I can't really reproduce the problem in stackblitz for now... I just need some delay for the initalization of the input in order to use it futher

Answer (score 0):

try move handling of the inputs when they are changed

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input() currentUser;

 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if(cnanges.currentUser && this.currentUser) {
   this.initializeForm(this.currentUser);
  }
}

initializeForm(user) {
... }
```